# Зачем в аргументах функции стоит form? JS

Tags: javascript

1.Я не понимаю что значит form в аргументе функции validation?

```
function validation(form){
    function createError(input,text){
        const parent = input.parentNode;
        const errorLabel = document.createElement('label');
        parent.classList.add("error");
        
    }
   let result = true;
   for(const input of allInput){
    if(input.value ==""){
        console.log("ошибка");
        createError(input, "поле не заполнено!");
        result = false;
    }
   }
   return result;
}

formValidation.addEventListener('submit',function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    validation(this)

    if(validation(this)==true){
        alert("Форма успешно отправлена!") 
        for (let i = 0; i < openPopup.length; i++) {
  openPopup[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    popupContainer.style.display = "flex";});
  popupContainer.addEventListener('click', function() { popupContainer.style.display = "none"});
  };  
    }
    
});

<form action="" class="form-validation"> 
            <div class="time-spending_form-input">
                <div class="time-spending_user-name">
                    <div class="input__error"><input type="text" class="time-spending-input time-spending_name" placeholder="Имя"></div>
                    <div class="input__error"><input type="text" class="time-spending-input time-spending_surname" placeholder="Фамилия"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="time-spending_user-contact">
                    <div class="input__error"><input type="text" class="time-spending-input time-spending_email" placeholder="Email"></div>
                    <div class="input__error"><input type="text" class="time-spending-input time-spending_phone" placeholder="Телефон"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
<button type="submit" class="button__reg button__reg-content time-spending-button">Зарегистрироваться</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: Просто так назван аргумент функции, правда в самой функции он не используется.

Comment: Тут `form` не аргумент, а параметр функции. Мне так же не понятно зачем он, т.к. внутри функции он не используется. Так же в твоем примере нет вызова самой функции `validation`...

Comment: Видимо, предполагается во входящей форме `form` найти все input'ы `allInput` и проверить их на наличие `value`, но объявление переменной `allInput` где-то потерялось.

Answer (score 0):

> Я не понимаю что значит form в аргументе функции validation?

Видимо автор кода, который вы где-то взяли, этот параметр использовал внутри функции, а потом перестал использовать, а параметр остался....А может наоборот, хотел использовать, но пока руки не дошли... В текущем виде он не нужен. Если как-то использовать - то нужен